# Remove everything before the URL text

Tags: javascript

I have this you URL passby my variable and somehow I get the URL differently, so I have to remove it.

My URL

```
http://localhost/Air.com/Img/team/12345/12345.png
```

I am using this code to remove it

```
Image_src = url
// Image_src = Image_src.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/+/i, "");
```

But somehow sometimes I have other URL, is there any way I can remove everything before /Img

```
Img/team/12345/12345.png
```

No matter what URL in front, remove everything before Img.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Image_src = url.substring(url.indexOf("/Img/"));
```

If you don't want the `/` character also just add 1, like so:

```
var Image_src = url.substring(url.indexOf("/Img/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://localhost/Air.com/Img/team/12345/12345.png";    
parser.pathname.substring(parser.pathname.indexOf('/',2)) // return /Img/team/12345/12345.png
```